# Merging two csv without pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I have two CSV files that I would like to merge. With pandas I would use:

> pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', left_on='ST_LOGINID', right_on='LOGINID')

However panda runs out of memory performing this operation ("MemoryError:"), although my RAM usage only goes from 1.9 GB to 2.2GB out of 4GB before the error is returned.

I am thus looking for either one of these solutions:
1) One way to perform such a merge/join operation without loading the files into memory
2) One way to allow pandas to use more RAM, since it seems that there is plenty of memory available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/scripts/csvjoin.html):

First install with:

```
pip install csvkit
```

Then:

```
csvjoin -c "ST_LOGINID, LOGINID" --outer file1.csv file2.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have huge CSV data, [NYSOL's mcmd](http://www.nysol.sakura.ne.jp/mcmd2/en/sect-mjoin.html) is the best.

```
mjoin k=ST_LOGINID K=LOGINID m=df2.csv i=df1.csv o=output.csv
```

It runs very first!

See more details [here](http://www.slideshare.net/SatoshiKitajima2/m1-38513054).